# when I quit element, and return after, behavior not same. Probably event.target

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

I've with inspect with my navigator my script and I finded the problem but I can't resolve this.

When, I've click on my element, he open a list, if click outside of this dropdown (On the document.body) and once again I click on this dropdown I can't selected a new value on my list. I think it's probably on my object.

```js
let open = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-container div');
for (let loop = 0; loop < open.length; loop++) {
  open[loop].addEventListener('click', () => {
    let tabLi = {};
    let list = open[loop].querySelectorAll('.tryit li')
    let cross = open[loop].querySelector('h3 .clear-filters');

    for (let l = 0; l < list.length; l++) {
      list[l].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (!list[l].classList.contains('active-dropdown')) {
          list[l].classList.add('active-dropdown');
          tabLi[l] = list[l];
          console.log(tabLi)
          cross.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          list[l].classList.remove('active-dropdown');
          delete tabLi[l];
          if (Object.keys(tabLi).length === 0) {
            cross.style.display = 'none';
          }
        }
      });
      cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        list[l].classList.remove('active-dropdown');
        delete tabLi[l];
        cross.style.display = 'none';
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You are assigning event listeners inside a loop... inside of another event listener. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: And If i use a removeEventListener ? when I close the dropdown ? 
Or if you have a best solution, I would  thanks